# Unable to push to a Bitbucket Mercurial Repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree with Bitbucket.

I used to be able to push without errors.

Now I get

```
hg push --new-branch default
pushing to https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository/branch/default
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I can see the repository in the browser.
I can push from a different machine. It works correctly on a machine where the url is `myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository`.

Comment: Mercurial should asks you for your username and password when pushing over HTTP. Did it asks prompt you for them? If not, try pushing to `https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository/branch/default` instead

Comment: It did not ask for a password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to drop the `branch/default` part of the URL. The canonical repository URL is `https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository/`.

For some reason, bitbucket allows read operations from `URL/more/stuff` but not write operations.

Comment: I can't access the problem machine at the moment, but it works correctly on a machine where the url is https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository